# Android gridview open image in foreground

Tags: android, image, gridview

I am able to create a grid view layout as shown  [Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)

when a image is clicked I would like to bring that image to the foreground (full screen) for 2 seconds and then go back to the grid layout.

Can you please point me to the appropriate examples/docs or pointers  on how to do this .


Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not currently in front of my programming computer so the following will be a little ad-hoc - below is what I would consider doing

1.) have your activity extend OnClickListener

2.) in your onClick, have it grab the view that was clicked and the image resource

3.) choose a method you feel would be best to show it (imageview/canvas/new Intent with dialog theme)

4.) have that new means display it fill_parent / fill_parent

5.) use some means to control the timer and dismiss itself (haven't played with this one much)

I know you'd like docs/examples, but I can't provide that at the moment, hope that offers a little bit of help